# Why is the leave-one-out error for support vector machines equal to the number of support vectors divided by the number of training examples?

Tags: classification, svm

Elementary question about support vector machines.

Given a support vector machine classifier and a linearly separable dataset. Why is the leave-one-out cross validation error said to be bounded by the number of support vectors divided by the number of training examples?

Comment: it is not so elementary question, the paper where this claim is proved is [Probabilistic kernel regression models, Tommi S Jaakkola and David Haussler, 1999](http://proceedings.mlr.press/r2/jaakkola99a/jaakkola99a.pdf)

Comment: The answer is in Lemma 1 (and proof in the appendix). In the case of linearly separable SVMs it degenerates to your question